# can add property or method to module simply using module.property?

Tags: javascript

```
const Test_module = (function () {

    let _private_prop = 'this is private';
    function _log () {
        //console.log(_new);
        return console.log(_private_prop);
    };

    return {
      log_Function: _log(),
    };

})();

Test_module._new = true;
console.log(Test_module._new);
```

Is this possible? Is there any wrong with this module? What happen in here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically Test_module is not really a JavaScript module. It's just a literal object returned by your IIFE (making _private_prop protected by closure). You can use Test_module like any object.

Comment: So what about module pattern ? How create a module? If there is a module is it behave like that ?

Comment: module pattern is the old way to create modules. Since ES6 or nodejs, there are other syntaxes. If you are not using webpack, or nodejs, but only scripts in html, the module pattern is still good.

Comment: If you are interested by module standards, see CJS (nodejs), UMD (web), and ESM (javascript since ES6)